# numpy partial rolling sum on condition

Tags: pandas, numpy

Suppose I have two 1D numpy array A and B, say they are generated by

```
A = np.array([random.randint(1,100) for _ in range(1000)])
```

and B in a similar way. Let's say the values are certain prices indexed by days over a period of time.

Suppose I would like to compute a partial rolling sum of A with a window = 20, in the following way: For each day, consider the values of B in the past 20 days, choose the 10 days with bigger B values, and then sum up the values of A in the corresponding 10 days.

With loops, it probably looks something like this:

```
result = np.zeros(A.shape)
for i in range(19, len(A)):
    window = list(zip(B[i - 19: i + 1], A[i - 19: i + 1]))
    window.sort(key = lambda x: x[0])
    result[i] = sum(window[1][10:])
```

This turns out to run very slowly because loops over numpy arrays are slow. I am wondering what is the 'numpy' way of doing this, i.e. without looping over the whole array.

Answer (score 1):

Since no one has posted any answer yet and I somewhat figured out a way to do it, I'm going to post it here. Any comment/suggestions/better answers are welcomed.

```
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import sliding_window_view
# create rolling windows of size 20 for both A and B
win_A = sliding_window_view(A, 20)
win_B = sliding_window_view(B, 20)
# compute and compare with the median for each rolling window in B
win_B = win_B > win_B.median(axis = -1)[:, None]
# computed the weighted sum
res = np.mean(win_A * win_B, axis = -1)
# drop the last dimension
res = res.reshape(A.shape[0] - 19)
# add Nan's at the front 
for i in range(19):
    res = np.insert(res, 0, np.nan)
```